# aggregation command over each two sequence row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table:

```
Date                        ID  val   vbl  vcl
2016-08-19 00:00:02         11  0      2    2
2016-08-20 00:00:07         22  2      2    1
2016-08-21 00:00:14         33  2      2    1
2016-08-22 00:00:28         22  0      2    2
2016-08-23 00:00:34         11  0      2    2
```

I want to run aggregation command (

```
select Id, sum(val), count(vcl)
from above_table
group by ID
```

over each two sequence rows.
For example do aggregation command for first and second row together then for third and fourth rows together.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions to enumerate the rows, and then do the aggregation:

```
select min(id), max(id), sum(val), count(vcl)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by date) - 1 as seqnum
      from above_table t
     ) t
group by (seqnum / 2);
```